# Using solr admin ui try to upload pdf file

Tags: solr, solrcloud, solr4, solrnet, sunspot-solr

My problem statement:-Using Solr admin Ui i want to upload pdf file and after submiting when i execute the query on solr ui then i want to see the content of that pdf file in response.

Implementation:- I created core with name pdfdemo i select that in Request handler input box i putted this /update/extract  and Extracting Req par I putted this literal.id=pdf1 uprefix= fmap.content=attr_content captureAttr=true after that click on submit Document instead of getting success message i got Red Error like this Not Found from /solr/pdfdemo/update/extract

I allredy make changes in pdfdemo config file and manage schema still my error is not get fixed please help me regard this. anyone please help if you have any idea about this

Comment: If you're getting 404 not found for the /extract endpoint - did you register the requestHandler and upload the necessary configuration?